# ESLint rules for no-unused-enums

Tags: typescript, enums, eslint

There's a `no-unused-vars` eslint rule that can warn/error if a variable is unused:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

If I want to ensure that there are no unused **enums**, what would be the best lint rule to implement?

Example scenario:

```js
export enum MyEnum {
  ONE = 'ONE',
  TWO = 'TWO',
  THREE = 'THREE',
}
```

Here `MyEnum.ONE` and `MyEnum.TWO` are both used, but `MyEnum.THREE` is not referenced.

```js
if (type === MyEnum.ONE) {
  ...
}

if (type === MyEnum.TWO) {
  ...
}
```

It would be great if a lint rule could warn/error that `MyEnum.THREE` is unused so that it may be removed.

Comment: That doesn't exist, and I doubt it's technically possible reliably. enums can be set and used from outside the project scope, so a global check would be more of an annoyance than help in most projects.

Comment: I am here because it does happen nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing rule to do this so you've got a couple of options:

1. Write your own rule (and publish it for the rest of us to use!)
2. If are you IntelliJ, then there is an inspection in the IDE ("Unused global symbol") that can give you the warning.

As an aside, make sure you are using the [Typescript version](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars) of no-unused-vars rule. Even then it doesn't detect unused exported variables because each file is analysed individually.